# What LEGO piece is this arc with ball joint?

Tags: part-identification

I cannot find a part number on it. It has the official logos on the studs. What is this? What theme does it originate from?[image: combination of a 4x4 plate, a 5x2 plate and an arc with a ball joint]

It looks like a combination of a 4x4 plate, a 5x2 plate and an arc with a ball joint.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is the [Vehicle, Trailer Base 4 x 13](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0085&name=Vehicle,%20Trailer%20Base%204%20x%2013&category=%5BVehicle,%20Base%5D#T=C&C=5). It came in one set, the [#378 Tractor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=378-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from 1972.

Found by searching first 4x9 (didn't find it) and then 4x13 (the total length).